# Problema input file Ajax-Upload carga 2 veces

Tags: jquery, ajax, fileupload, upload

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy cargando archivos con la Libreria Ajax-Upload , pero cuando cargo el archivo este se vuelve a levantar , el archivo se guarda en mi servidor, pero la ventana vuelve a levantarse 
¿A que se puede deber este problema ? 
En el jsfiddle coloque de forma manual el script debido a que no encontre el CDN saludos gracias estaré atento a sus respuestas

```js
/*! Ajax-Upload - v2.0.2 - 2016-02-18 - Uses native XHR to upload files.
* https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Ajax-Upload
* Copyright (c) Han Lin Yap http://yap.nu; MIT license
* == Example Usage ==
* $.ajaxUpload({
* url: 'upload.php',
* data: ':file',
* success: function (data, status, xhr) {
*  console.log(data);
* }
* });
*/
/* --- Other polyfills --- */
//no encontre el cdn de ajax uplaod por eso pongo el codigo de forma man
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
 var noop = function () {};
 var console = (window.console = window.console || {});
 
 if (!console.log) {
  console.log = noop;
 }
}());

/* --- Ajax Upload --- */
(function ($) {
 'use strict';

 // Prevent to read twice
 if ($.ajaxUpload) {
  return;
 }

 $.ajaxUploadSettings = {
  //onloadstart : function(e){},
  onprogress : function(e){ console.log('Ajax Upload progress'); },
  onabort  : function(e){ console.log('Ajax Upload abort'); },
  onerror  : function(e){ console.log('Ajax Upload error'); console.log(e); },
  onload   : function(e){ console.log('Ajax Upload load'); },
  //ontimeout  : function(e){},
  //onloadend  : function(e){},
  name  : 'uploads[]'
 };

 $.ajaxUploadSerializeFiles = function( element ) {
  var data = [];
  var name = $(element).attr('name');
  for(var i = 0, len = element.files.length; i < len; i++) {
   data.push({
    'name' : name, 
    'value': element.files[i]
   });
  }
  return data;
 };

 /**
  * @param array kv [{name, value},..]
  * @param FormData exist Existing FormData
  */
 $.ajaxUploadToFormData = function( kv, exist ) {
  var fd = exist || new FormData();
  for(var i = 0, len = kv.length; i < len; i++) {
   fd.append(kv[i].name, kv[i].value);
  }
  return fd;
 };

 $.ajaxUploadExtractData = function( data, exist ) {
  if ( !data/* || $.isArray(data)*/ || data instanceof FormData ) return data;
  var fd = $.ajaxUploadExtractData(exist) || new FormData();
  if ( typeof data === "string" || data instanceof jQuery ) {
   var kv = [];
   $(data).each(function (index, element) {
    $.merge( kv, $.ajaxUploadSerializeFiles(this) );
   });
   data = kv;
  } else if (data instanceof FileList) {
   var kv = [];
   for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    kv.push({
     'name' : $.ajaxUploadSettings.name, 
     'value': data[i]
    });
   }
   data = kv;
  } else if (typeof data === "object" && !$.isArray(data)) {
   var temp = [];
   for(name in data) {
    temp.push({
     'name': name,
     'value': data[name]
    });
   }
   data = temp;
  }
  return $.ajaxUploadToFormData(data, fd);
 };

 /**
  * All available options as $.ajax() except
  * contentType
  * processData
  * type
  */
 $.ajaxUpload = function(origSettings) {

  // Merge Global settings
  var s = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $.ajaxUploadSettings, origSettings);

  // Normalize data
  var fd = $.ajaxUploadExtractData(s.data);
  //fd = $.ajaxUploadToFormData(fd);
  // Set nessessery settings
  s.data = null;
  var nesseserySettings = {
   processData : false,
   type: 'POST',
   beforeSend : function(xhr, s) {
    s.xhr = function () {
     var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.upload.onprogress = s.onprogress.bind(this);
     xhr.upload.onabort = s.onabort.bind(this);
     xhr.upload.onerror = s.onerror.bind(this);
     xhr.upload.onload = s.onload.bind(this);
     return xhr;
    };
    s.data = fd;
    if (origSettings.beforeSend) {
     return origSettings.beforeSend.call(this, xhr, s);
    }
   }
  };
  s = jQuery.extend(true, {}, s, nesseserySettings);
  // make sure dont overwrites multipart
  if (s.contentType) {
   delete s.contentType;
  }
  // Upload
  return $.ajax(s);
 };

 $.fn.ajaxUpload = function( origSettings ) {
  return this.each(function() {
   var options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, origSettings);
   var data = $(this).serializeArray();

   $('input:file', this).each(function (index, element) {
    $.merge( data, $.ajaxUploadSerializeFiles(this) );
   });
   
   options.data = $.ajaxUploadExtractData(data, options.data);
   
   $.ajaxUpload(options);
  });
 };

 $.ajaxUploadPost = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
  // shift arguments if data argument was omited
  if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
   type = type || callback;
   callback = data;
   data = {};
  }

  return $.ajaxUpload({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: callback,
   dataType: type
  });
 };

 $.ajaxUploadPrompt = function( options ) {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  var nesseserySettings = {
   success : function () {
    if (options.success) {
     options.success.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    form.remove();
   }
  };

  var s = jQuery.extend(true, {}, options, nesseserySettings);
  var id = 'ajaxupload' + Date.now();
  var form = $('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />').appendTo('body');
  form.attr('action', s.url);
  form.attr('target', id);

  form.css({
   position: 'relative',
   top: -1000,
   left: -1000,
   opacity: 0
  });
  form.submit(function () { //alert($(':file', this).val()); 
  });
    
  var d = $('<input type="file" />').appendTo(form);
  d.attr('name', $.ajaxUploadSettings.name);

  if (options.accept) {
   d.attr('accept', options.accept);
  }

  if (options.multiple) {
   d.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
  }

  d.change(function() {
   if (!this.files.length) {
    return false;
   }

   if (!s.data) {
    s.data = {};
   }

   s.files = this.files;
   s.data = $.ajaxUploadExtractData(s.data, $.ajaxUploadSerializeFiles(this));

   $.ajaxUpload(s).promise(def);
  });
  d.click();
  
  return def;
 };
 
 // bind a click event
 $.fn.ajaxUploadPrompt = function( origSettings ) {
  return this.click(function () {
   $(this).trigger('ajaxUploadPrompt', $.ajaxUploadPrompt( origSettings ));
  });
 };

 // bind a drop event
 $.fn.ajaxUploadDrop = function( origSettings ) {
  return this.each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);

   $this.on('dragenter.ajaxUpload', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

    $this.addClass('dragover');
    
   }).on('dragover.ajaxUpload', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    
    $this.addClass('dragover');

   }).on('dragleave.ajaxUpload', function(e) {
    $this.removeClass('dragover');

   }).on('drop.ajaxUpload', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;  
    var files = dt.files;       
    var options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, origSettings);
    
    options.data = $.ajaxUploadExtractData(files, options.data);
    options.files = files; 
    
    $this.trigger('ajaxUploadDrop', $.ajaxUpload(options));

    $this.removeClass('dragover');
   });
  });
 };
})(jQuery);




//asigno ajax upload al input
$(function(){

  $.ajaxUploadSettings.name = 'file';
  // Set promptzone
  $('#promptzone').ajaxUploadPrompt({
  url: '<?php print base_url();?>urlejemplo',
  success : function (data) {

  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="promptzone">Adjuntar Archivo</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="promptzone">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas llamando a la función propia del input file y luego se ejecuta la función del plugin, tienes que escuchar el evento click y llamar a la funcion del plugin

```
$(function(){

  $.ajaxUploadSettings.name = 'file';
  // Set promptzone
  $('#promptzone').click(ajaxUploadPrompt({
  url: '<?php print base_url();?>urlejemplo',
  success : function (data) {

  }
  }));
});
```

Comment: gracias , era como comentabas ejecutaba el type="file" y ademas el plugin por eso levantaba dos veces el modal de upload file.